# "Send via Phone Call" button grayed out / disabled while trying to register for Facebook developer account

Tags: facebook

I am trying to register for a Facebook developer account. So I went to developers.facebook.com and then tried to go through the registration process. During the steps, facebook requires me to provide my phone number in order to receive a confirmation code for registration. A dialog box shows up and I enter my phone number in it. But even after I do this, I am unable to click on "Send via Phone Call" button because it is grayed out / disabled as shown below. Please note that I have just put a fake phone number for the image here, but the button won't enable in spite of my putting my real phone number.

[image]

All I could do is click on "Send as Text". But the problem with that is the fact my phone can't receive text messages. So I am stuck, because I can't click on the "Send via Phone Call" and receive a call on my phone for the confirmation code.

Could someone please let me know how I get around this and complete the registration process for the developer account? Either having a way to enable the "Send via Phone Call" button or having a way to register without a phone number or another way that I am not aware of would be good.

Thanks.

Comment: Send via Phone Call have been disable because it was buggy I think. So I think you would have to wait until the bug have been fix.

Comment: I see. Can't believe facebook hasn't fixed it. That is unfortunate. Looks like I need to activate text plan on my phone, since that would be the only other alternative.

Comment: I think http://blog.shubh.am/how-i-bypassed-2-factor-authentication-on-google-yahoo-linkedin-and-many-others/ was the reason for it

Comment: wow. Thanks for the helpful link. Don't know how to react. One would think that these multi-billion dollar companies would have security tested these features in a bullet proof manner. But looks like they haven't and it took an individual to point out to the vulnerabilities. What a shame. No wonder hackers are having a good time.

Comment: I think you totally missed something. Many big IT-companies have big whitehat programs where external people can report security issues and get payed for them. You can read about Facebooks at https://www.facebook.com/whitehat

Comment: Hmm, I see. Good point. While I do think this is a great idea, IMHO that should only be a fallback and not a primary means of discovering security issues.

Comment: It is not the primary means. It is just one way we find bugs

Comment: I actually found a way to bypass it. If you're a techie, just do an "Inspect Element" on that button and remove the `disabled` attribute. The Look will still remain grayed out but calling will work!

Answer (score 1):

I think [the original comment by Tzar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006640/send-via-phone-call-button-grayed-out-disabled-while-trying-to-register-for/34808433#comment41938977_24006640) deserves to be an answer as its 2016 and still, works:

Short story:

The Send via phone call button is greyed out and disabled, but the functionality exists. Facebook just made a lazy/temp/quickfix by just disabling the control, not removing the functionality. What that means is if you can simply enable the button, it will work. So we need to tamper with that html.

Solution:

Do an inspect element with your browser on that button, and simply remove the `disabled="1"` property. **Here is the tricky part:** the button will remain greyed-out but it **will be clickable**, and i can confirm it just worked for me.